# Data from SQL Server table to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, etl

I've got 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData] 
(
    [Data] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [DataType] AS (SUBSTRING([Data], (3), (3)))
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDataTypes] 
(
    DataTypeID varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    DateTypeName varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Here is some test data:

```
INSERT INTO TestDataTypes (DataTypeID, DateTypeName) 
VALUES ('010', 'DataHeader'),
       ('020', 'SectionHeader'),
       ('030', 'SectionData'),
       ('080', 'SectionFooter'),
       ('090','DataFooter');

INSERT INTO TestData ([Data]) 
VALUES ('FI0103146701200242606660000000000000000000020210908074601P'),
       ('FI020836740675301000031012700000000000000000000000020210908074601'),
       ('FI03020210907710000000002395847961930920210907018990006320210908000000000689708 CC000000000N'),
       ('FI03020210907710000000002396398519301520210907395125022320210908000000000016036 CC000000000N'),
       ('FI03020210907710000000002392918856530120210907738990002520210908000000000024424 CC000000000N'),
       ('FI0808367406700000000154000000023679373000000000000000'),
       ('FI09031467012002426066600000000000000000000100000000154');
```

Now I can join my data

```
SELECT
    TD.DataType, TDT.DateTypeName, TD.[data] 
FROM
    TestData AS TD
INNER JOIN
    TestDataTypes TDT ON TD.DataType = TDT.DataTypeID
```

Output:

```
010   DataHeader      FI0103146701200242606660000000000000000000020210908074601P
020   SectionHeader   FI020836740675301000031012700000000000000000000000020210908074601
030   SectionData     FI03020210907710000000002395847961930920210907018990006320210908000000000689708 CC000000000N
030   SectionData     FI03020210907710000000002396398519301520210907395125022320210908000000000016036 CC000000000N
030   SectionData     FI03020210907710000000002392918856530120210907738990002520210908000000000024424 CC000000000N
080   SectionFooter   FI0808367406700000000154000000023679373000000000000000
090   DataFooter      FI09031467012002426066600000000000000000000100000000154
```

How can I get it to be like this in XML:

```
<DataHeader DataType="010" girodata="FI0103146701200242606660000000000000000000020210908074601P" >
    <SectionHeader DataType="020" girodata="FI020836740675301000031012700000000000000000000000020210908074601" >
        <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002395847961930920210907018990006320210908000000000689708 CC000000000N" ></SectionData>
        <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002396398519301520210907395125022320210908000000000016036 CC000000000N" ></SectionData>
        <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002392918856530120210907738990002520210908000000000024424 CC000000000N" ></SectionData>
    </SectionHeader>
    <SectionFooter DataType="080" girodata="FI0808367406700000000154000000023679373000000000000000"></SectionFooter>
    <DataFooter DataType="090" girodata="FI09031467012002426066600000000000000000000100000000154"></GiroFooter>
</DataHeader>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`FOR XML EXPLICIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-ver15) to achieve this.

While using `EXPLICIT` can be more verbose than it's counterparts `RAW`, `AUTO`, it easily gives you the level of control desired for your output that uses nested nodes with specific attributes. It is important to note that there are `Tag` (as integer) and `Parent` columns which indicate tag ids respectively and their associated parents. The remaining columns use the column naming format `<NODE_NAME>!<TagId>!<AttributeName>`. Ideally you would output `NULL` values where the data is not required (I've used case expressions to achieve this below) as this would result in less data being returned to the client but it works either way and I have included several alternatives below which you may choose from along with a working demo fiddle. I've also filtered using a where clause based on your desired `DataType`s or nodes.

**Recommended**

```sql
SELECT
     CAST(TD.DataType AS INT) as Tag,
     CASE 
         WHEN TD.DataType='010' THEN NULL 
         WHEN TD.DataType='030' THEN 20
         ELSE 10 
     END as Parent,
     
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='010' THEN TD.DataType END as 'DataHeader!010!DataType',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='010' THEN TD.[data] END as 'DataHeader!010!girodata',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='020' THEN TD.DataType END as 'SectionHeader!020!DataType',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='020' THEN TD.[data] END  as 'SectionHeader!020!girodata',
     
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='030' THEN TD.DataType END as 'SectionData!030!DataType',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='030' THEN TD.[data] END as 'SectionData!030!girodata',
     
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='080' THEN TD.DataType END as 'SectionFooter!080!DataType',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='080' THEN TD.[data] END as 'SectionFooter!080!girodata',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='090' THEN TD.DataType END as 'DataFooter!090!DataType',
     CASE WHEN TD.DataType='090' THEN TD.[data] END as 'DataFooter!090!girodata'
FROM TestData as TD 
WHERE TD.DataType IN ('010','020','080','090','030')
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

**Other Alternatives**

```sql
WITH my_data AS (
     SELECT 
         TD.DataType,TDT.DateTypeName,TD.[data] as dataval
     FROM TestData as TD 
     INNER JOIN TestDataTypes TDT on TD.DataType = TDT.DataTypeID
     WHERE DataType IN ('010','020','080','090','030')
)
SELECT
     CAST(DataType AS INT) as Tag,
     CASE 
         WHEN DateTypeName='DataHeader' THEN NULL 
         WHEN DateTypeName='SectionData' THEN 20
         ELSE 10 
     END as Parent,
     
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='DataHeader' THEN DataType END as 'DataHeader!010!DataType',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='DataHeader' THEN dataval END as 'DataHeader!010!girodata',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionHeader' THEN DataType END as 'SectionHeader!020!DataType',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionHeader' THEN dataval END as 'SectionHeader!020!girodata',
     
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionData' THEN DataType END as 'SectionData!030!DataType',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionData' THEN dataval END as 'SectionData!030!girodata',
     
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionFooter' THEN DataType END as 'SectionFooter!080!DataType',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='SectionFooter' THEN dataval END as 'SectionFooter!080!girodata',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='DataFooter' THEN DataType END as 'DataFooter!090!DataType',
     CASE WHEN DateTypeName='DataFooter' THEN dataval END as 'DataFooter!090!girodata'
FROM my_data
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

or less verbose

```sql
WITH my_data AS (
     SELECT 
         TD.DataType,TDT.DateTypeName,TD.[data] as dataval
     FROM TestData as TD 
     INNER JOIN TestDataTypes TDT on TD.DataType = TDT.DataTypeID
     WHERE DataType IN ('010','020','080','090','030')
)
SELECT
     CAST(DataType AS INT) as Tag,
     CASE 
         WHEN DateTypeName='DataHeader' THEN NULL 
         WHEN DateTypeName='SectionData' THEN 20
         ELSE 10 
     END as Parent,
     
     DataType as 'DataHeader!010!DataType',
     dataval  as 'DataHeader!010!girodata',
     DataType as 'SectionHeader!020!DataType',
     dataval  as 'SectionHeader!020!girodata',
     
     DataType as 'SectionData!030!DataType',
     dataval as 'SectionData!030!girodata',
     
     DataType as 'SectionFooter!080!DataType',
     dataval as 'SectionFooter!080!girodata',
     DataType as 'DataFooter!090!DataType',
     dataval as 'DataFooter!090!girodata'
FROM my_data
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

or

```sql
SELECT
     CAST(TD.DataType AS INT) as Tag,
     CASE 
         WHEN TDT.DateTypeName='DataHeader' THEN NULL 
         WHEN TDT.DateTypeName='SectionData' THEN 20
         ELSE 10 
     END as Parent,
     
     TD.DataType as 'DataHeader!010!DataType',
     TD.[data]  as 'DataHeader!010!girodata',
     TD.DataType as 'SectionHeader!020!DataType',
     TD.[data]  as 'SectionHeader!020!girodata',
     
     TD.DataType as 'SectionData!030!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'SectionData!030!girodata',
     
     TD.DataType as 'SectionFooter!080!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'SectionFooter!080!girodata',
     TD.DataType as 'DataFooter!090!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'DataFooter!090!girodata'
FROM TestData as TD 
INNER JOIN TestDataTypes TDT on TD.DataType = TDT.DataTypeID
WHERE TD.DataType IN ('010','020','080','090','030')
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

or more efficient without the join

```sql
SELECT
     CAST(TD.DataType AS INT) as Tag,
     CASE 
         WHEN TD.DataType='010' THEN NULL 
         WHEN TD.DataType='030' THEN 20
         ELSE 10 
     END as Parent,
     
     TD.DataType as 'DataHeader!010!DataType',
     TD.[data]  as 'DataHeader!010!girodata',
     TD.DataType as 'SectionHeader!020!DataType',
     TD.[data]  as 'SectionHeader!020!girodata',
     
     TD.DataType as 'SectionData!030!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'SectionData!030!girodata',
     
     TD.DataType as 'SectionFooter!080!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'SectionFooter!080!girodata',
     TD.DataType as 'DataFooter!090!DataType',
     TD.[data] as 'DataFooter!090!girodata'
FROM TestData as TD 
WHERE TD.DataType IN ('010','020','080','090','030')
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

*Workding demo db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=919500f6088341cc8a85789798fd68d9)*

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much easier method to achieve the task.

It is using standard XML API: XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

This method allows to compose XML *'visually'* in two steps:

1. Create raw XML via `FOR XML ...`.
2. Compose exact output XML via XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TestData TABLE ([Data] [varchar](2000) NULL, [DataType] AS (SUBSTRING([Data], (3), (3))));
INSERT INTO @TestData ([Data]) VALUES 
('FI0103146701200242606660000000000000000000020210908074601P'),
('FI020836740675301000031012700000000000000000000000020210908074601'),
('FI03020210907710000000002395847961930920210907018990006320210908000000000689708 CC000000000N'),
('FI03020210907710000000002396398519301520210907395125022320210908000000000016036 CC000000000N'),
('FI03020210907710000000002392918856530120210907738990002520210908000000000024424 CC000000000N'),
('FI0808367406700000000154000000023679373000000000000000'),
('FI09031467012002426066600000000000000000000100000000154');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT * FROM @TestData
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<DataHeader DataType="010" girodata="{/root/r[DataType/text()="010"]/Data}" >
    <SectionHeader DataType="020" girodata="{/root/r[DataType/text()="020"]/Data}" >
    {
        for $x in /root/r[DataType/text()="030"]
        return <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="{$x/Data}"></SectionData>
    }
    </SectionHeader>
    <SectionFooter DataType="080" girodata="{/root/r[DataType/text()="080"]/Data}"></SectionFooter>
    <DataFooter DataType="090" girodata="{/root/r[DataType/text()="090"]/Data}"></DataFooter>
</DataHeader>');
```

**Output**

```
<DataHeader DataType="010" girodata="FI0103146701200242606660000000000000000000020210908074601P">
  <SectionHeader DataType="020" girodata="FI020836740675301000031012700000000000000000000000020210908074601">
    <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002395847961930920210907018990006320210908000000000689708 CC000000000N" />
    <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002396398519301520210907395125022320210908000000000016036 CC000000000N" />
    <SectionData DataType="030" girodata="FI03020210907710000000002392918856530120210907738990002520210908000000000024424 CC000000000N" />
  </SectionHeader>
  <SectionFooter DataType="080" girodata="FI0808367406700000000154000000023679373000000000000000" />
  <DataFooter DataType="090" girodata="FI09031467012002426066600000000000000000000100000000154" />
</DataHeader>
```